# Why do i get start of season squads when creating a custom tournament?

Tags: fifa-14

My squads are updated via EA networks, and when playing Kick-off games I get the latest squads with the January transfers. But when I start a new custom tournament, the squads reset to the start of season squads, few days before the end of the Summer Transfer window.

How do I get the updated squads here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the latest squads manually in Customize>Edit Teams.

It doesn't change the default teams if it says "downloading latest online squads" on its own, you have to do it.